# JsPDF Autotable adding Images to column gives error: Property 'getElementsByTagName' does not exist

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to add an image from AWS S3 bucket using its url, with the format of the data looking like:

```
[{
  netValue: 13702.5,
  prodCode: "UPP",
  prodDesc: "Privacy Panel",
  prodImg: "https://url/images/UPP02.png",
  prodQty: 20,
  unitPrice: 870
}]
```

With the table in my html file looking like:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive-xxl table-bordered" id="prodTable" #prodTable>
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-reflow">
            <th>S. N</th>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Qty</th>      
            <th>Price</th>      
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let prod of prodDetailsArr; let i = index">
            <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ prod.prodCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ prod.prodDesc }}</td>
            <td><img [src]="prod.prodImg"></td>
            <td>{{ prod.prodQty }}</td>
            <td>{{ prod.unitPrice }}</td>
            <td>{{ prod.netValue }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the table being displayed without its image in the PDF file, I tried using the code below to access it, but I get the following errors that stop compiling, even though console.log(td) gives the proper img and its src:

```
autoTable(doc, { 
      html: '#prodTable',
      startY: 200,                    
      theme: 'plain',
      tableLineColor: [0, 0, 0],
      tableLineWidth: 0.5,
      margin: {
        left: 5,
        right: 7
      },
      didDrawCell: function(data) {
        if (data.column.index === 3 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
          var td = data.cell.raw;
          console.log(td)
          var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
          var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical');
          doc.addImage(img.src, data.cell.x,  data.cell.y, dim, dim);         
        }
      }
    })
```

> Property 'getElementsByTagName' does not exist on type 'HTMLTableCellElement | CellInput'.
> Property 'getElementsByTagName' does not exist on type 'string'.

And when I try to save pdf, I get:

> zone-evergreen.js:2981 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url/images/UPP02.png' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> ERROR Error: addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN', please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support is added.
> at Object.P (jspdf.es.min.js:86:93253)
> at push../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js.e.addImage

[Here is a stackblitz illustrating the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mkg8wy?file=src%2Fmain.ts) When I try to insert image into the table, I get an error stating "Incomplete or corrupt PNG File". I'm using jspdf: ^2.5.1, and jspdf-autotable: ^3.5.31, alongside angular 8.

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st issue, the `td` variable is `HTMLTableCellElement | CellInput` type.

The [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) is only available from the `Element` type and `HTMLTableCellElement` inherits the `Element` type.

Thus you have to cast the `td` as `HTMLTableCellElement`.

Either

```
var img = (td as HTMLTableCellElement).getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

or

```
var td= data.cell.raw as HTMLTableCellElement;
```

For the 2nd issue, it seems the problem came from the AWS S3 Bucket which implements the CORS and blocks your Angular app from accessing as it is not *whitelisted*.

You should configure the CORS rule to allow (whitelist) the Angular application IP (if it is exposed to the public) in *AllowedOrigins*. Or enforce the wildcard (*) rule for *AllowedOrigins* but you may bear the risk as this will allow all origins. You may refer to [CORS configuration for AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html).

Comment: I'm afraid I still get the same issue. Could there be any other underlying issue that could possibly throw this error up?

Comment: I'm afraid I still get the same issue. Which issue did you mean?

Comment: The addImage function reading Properties of UNKOWN. There shouldn't be any issue with CORS and S3 since image upload and retrieval works, and I'm also able to display the image onto the table in html. The problem must lie in the jspdf auto table declaration.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in StsckBlitz and provide the jspdf-autotable version that you used?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mkg8wy?file=src%2Fmain.ts  Here it is. When I try to insert image into the table, I get an error stating "Incomplete or corrupt PNG File". I'm using jspdf: ^2.5.1, and jspdf-autotable: ^3.5.31, alongside angular 8

Comment: I checked your StackBlitz demo, but I couldn't see any error "Incomplete or corrupt PNG File"

Comment: Were you able to generate a pdf file with the required output when you click print? It should be displaying the table in the preview.

Comment: Hi, yes I clicked the Print button and check the console, no prompt any error message as you mentioned, and it populates the PDF with images correctly.